# R change legend order from alphabetical to numerical

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How can I change the order of legend elements to the numerical values instead of the alphabetical in ggplot? So i want to go from 1,10,2,3 to 1,2,3,10.

I know that i can set the order by hand for each graph separetely but I want to do automatically.

```
df <- data.frame(
  group=c("1_text","1_text","1_text","2_text","2_text","2_text", "10_text",
           "10_text","10_text"," 3_text","3_text","3_text"),
                 x=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                 y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) )

ggplot(df,aes(x=x))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y=y,color=group)
```

I assume that I need to safe the group column as.factor(df$group) and then sort it by levels. With something like that:

```
sorted_group <- paste(sort(as.numeric(levels(df$group))))
```

However because my df$group elements aren't numerical it doesn't work.
Is there a way to maybe do it directly in ggplot without doing changes on the dataframe itself?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use the answer posted but to extract the numeric part of the string you can do something like: 
df <- 
  data.frame(
  group1 = c(
    "1_text",
    "1_text",
    "1_text",
    "2_text",
    "2_text",
    "2_text",
    "10_text",
    "10_text",
    "10_text",
    "3_text",
    "3_text",
    "3_text"
  ),
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
) %>%
  mutate(grp_num = parse_number(as.character(group1))) %>% 
  arrange(grp_num) %>% 
  mutate(group1 = factor(group1, levels = unique(group1)))

Comment: FYI parse_number comes from the readr package

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have already tried a similar approach by splitting the "group elements" in two parts with the separate function and simply writing it to a new column. However, this way it just plots the numbers as legend elements without keeping the "text" that comes after the numbers.

Comment: I have tried around with your code and understood how your approach is different. Thank you very much!